# Back to Previous App iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am currently in App 'A'.
From 'A' I switch to App 'B' via OpenURL.
Now from App 'B' I switch to App 'C'
On the top i see a 'Back to B' link on top.

BUT I WANT to go back to App 'A' directly from App 'C' without using OpenURL.

How do i customize this default back feature in iOS.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you are targeting for. That's default OS behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't do that, it is an IOS default feature and you can't change this feature by your own, Also apple has not given any kind of option for that to customising this kind of settings for iOS user.